# Adding <options> to a <select> element dynamically just before the user opens it

Tags: javascript, jquery

All,

I'm working on a web app. One of the key screens contains a fairly large table - typically between 50-100 rows.

On each row, I've got two `<select>` elements; each contains anywhere from 10-30 `<option>` elements.

If I were to include all `<option>` elements on each `<select>` on each row, I could end up with more than 6,000 elements (100 rows x 2 selects x 30 options).

So, my plan was to limit each select to a single option (the selected option). Then, when the user clicked the select, I would use JavaScript/jQuery to populate the options.

Then, after the user closes the select, I'd remove all but the selected option.

Importantly, I'm triggering the JavaScript function that adds the options on the `focus` event.

In Chrome and Firefox - this works great.

I've set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/j2zfD/

However, in IE - it doesn't work properly. Initially, when you click the select - instead of showing the menu - it simply focuses inside the select. If you click the select AGAIN, it then shows the menu. I'm **guessing** that's because IE tries to display the menu **BEFORE** firing the `focus` event.

Bottom line - this is unacceptable because you need to click the select **twice** to display the menu of options.

It also doesn't work properly **sometimes** in Safari on iOS. (Perhaps because there's a race condition between building the menu and firing the focus event...)

I've experimented with moving my logic to the `mousedown` event, but that seems to cause more problems, because mousedown is fired not only when you click into the select, but also when you click any of the options.

I'm guessing that this approach (adding options to a select when you need them) has been implemented successfully thousands of times; I just need a little advice on how to do it properly.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if you could satisfice and handle the population based on which rows are visible on the screen. As the viewport is scrolled, remove the <option>s from the <select>s that are no longer visible. For efficiency, you could simply detach them and move them to the new parent. Especially on mobile, this would mean only having a few on screen at a time. Another option would be to populate them when mouse enters the parent element of the <select>. For instance, if it's a table, set it to populate on tr:hover.

Comment: why don't you just use one `select` for whole page and display it on a per row basis as needed

Comment: @charlietfl - I'd like to do something like that. How would you implement it? (E.g., you need something that the user can click to know when to show the `select`...)

Comment: I might have been able to resolve this myself - by using the "focusin" event instead of "focus" - it now seems to work properly on all desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE8+). And, I'm using "touchstart" instead of "focusin" on mobile devices (detecting touch capabilities with Modernizr). All in all, seems to work.

Comment: use hover to display select in correct place

Comment: @mattstuehler i tried the code with `focusin` but still i need to double click in IE 9...if it is working fine for you can you please share a sample code which is working fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<select class="sel">
    <option value="a">Option A</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var option={
        "a":"option a",
        "b":"option b",
        "c":"option c"
    };
    $('.sel').on('click',function(){
        $('.sel').html('');
       $.each(option,function(i,n){
          $('.sel').append('<option value='+i+'>'+n+'</option>');
        });

    });
    $('.sel').on('change',function(){
        var selected_val=$(this).val();
        var selected_option=$("option:selected",this).text();
        $('.sel').html('');

          $('.sel').append('<option value='+selected_val+'>'+selected_option+'</option>');

    });

});
```

here is the demo :http://jsfiddle.net/mHGQs/

Comment: Peeyush - thank you for your suggestion. It's actually pretty similar to what I have, only it works slightly worse (on Chrome and IE at least). The issue, I think, is that you're building the menu on `click`, which is too late. I'm using `focus`, which happens before `click`, and even that seems to be too late on IE.